# Why is this independent?

Tags: statistics

My only question is how did they get that the two samples are independent? I'm not really sure how they drew this conclusion. Thank you in advance!

The highlighted portion below problems a-d is given in the answer. We're not told that in the question, just to be clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the question is stipulating that the samples are independent, then asking you some questions based on that information.  They are not concluding that the samples are independent.

Comment: Oh... Er, sorry, then how did they stipulate that? Cause I can't see where in the question you can say "ok these are independent" :^(

Comment: It looks like the sentence below a-d is a clarification of the question.

Comment: Ohhh, yeah no that's in the //answer//. We're not given it in the question. I'll change the question so that's more clear, my bad. But yeah we're not given that in the question which is why I'm confused how they got that it's independent.

Comment: Usually when a statistics book says you have two (random) samples, you are supposed to assume they are independent samples even if that is not explicitly stated. If the samples are not independent, there is usually some explanation how they are connected. (I am not defending this sloppiness, just reporting that I have often observed it.)